# Multiple user logon in Spring using c3p0

Tags: spring, c3p0

In my application I am using c3p0 for connection pooling. I provide the username and password in the context file.Configuration is below:

```
<bean id="datasource"
            class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${url}" />
            <property name="user" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />    </bean>
```

when my application loads then Spring made a connection using this username and password.
Now the problem is if any other user come and login with his profile using directly my login page then i want to replace the Springs connection with the new user's connection.So the data fetching is done with the new user's profile my client doesn't want to change in the properties file.
Pls assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, it doesn't make any sense to have a connection pool since every session will need to open it's own connection.

You'd be better off opening a connection when a user logs in and then maintaining the same connection in the session scope. Or opening a new connection each time you need it, but that's an extra overhead you might want to avoid. Just be careful about resource leakage. Since each user that logs in needs their own connection, you'll need to set session timeouts pretty low to avoid having masses of open connections in abandoned sessions.

Comment: Ok ur right but as you said I am not able to use Springs DI feature.Because my connection is used by Spring while creating the entitymanager factory object and when we open a connection outside the spring's context then how can I set this connection in the spring's context

Comment: I'm certain this can be accomplished, but it's not super-trivial and will probably involve some custom components from you. One approach that springs to mind is to create your own session-scoped data-source implementation to use with the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. In you session-scoped custom datasource, you will need to manually create and maintain the connection for that users session.